# If function(x) can work, why would we need function()?

Tags: r

I understand how "function(x)" works, but what is the role of "function()" here?

```
z <- function() {
  y <- 2
  function(x) {
    x + y
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question really is unclear. I suspect I see what's bothering you, but I'm not sure. [This page](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/pathways/cpp1/node160.html) might help, though it's about a different programming language. A function in a programming language isn't quite like a mathematical function: it's more like a list of instructions that do something when you apply the function to its **possibly empty** list of arguments.

Comment: It's fine; my instructor could not explain his stuff either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`function` is a keyword which is part of the creation of a function (in the programming sense that [Gilles describes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884311/892313)). The other parts are the argument list (in parentheses) and the function body (in braces).

In your example, `z` is a function which takes no arguments. It returns a function which takes 1 argument (named `x`) (since R returns the last evaluated statement as the return value by default). That function returns its argument `x` plus 2.

When `z` is called (with no arguments: `z()`) it assigns 2 to `y` (inside the functions variable scope, an additional concept that I'm not going to get into). Then it creates a function (without a name) which takes a single argument named `x`, which, when itself called, returns its argument `x` plus 2. That anonymous function is returned from the call to `z` and, presumably, stored so that it can be called later.

See https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functions and https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functionals for more discussion on passing around functions as objects.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and understanding my question.

Comment: So lines 3 and 5 really should be indented the same as line 2, right?

Answer (score 3):

The word “function” means somewhat different things in [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) and in [programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28computer_science%29). In mathematics, a function is a correspondence between each possible value of the parameters and a result. In programming, a function is a sequence of instructions to compute the result from the parameters.

In mathematics, a function with no argument is a constant. In programming, this is not the case, because functions can have [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29), such as printing something. So you will encounter many functions with no arguments in programs.

Hre the function `function(x) { x + y }` depends on the variable `y`. There are no side effects, so this function is very much like the mathematical function defined by $f(x) = x + y$. However, this definition is only complete for a given value of `y`. The previous instruction sets `y` to 2, so

```
function() {
  y <- 2
  function(x) {
    x + y
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function () {
  function(x) {
    x + 2
  }
}
```

in the sense that both definitions produce the same results when applied to the same value. They are, however, computed in slightly different ways.

That function is given the name `z`. When you call `z` (with no argument, so you write `z()`), this builds the function `function (x) { x + 2 }`, or something equivalent: `z()` is a function of one argument that adds 2 to its argument. So you can write something like `z()(3)` — the result is 5.

This is obviously a toy example. As you progress in your lectures, you'll see progressively more complex examples where such function building is mixed with other features to achieve useful things.

Comment: The paragraph before the last one is really helpful; thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

With [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884346/identify-all-functions-with-an-empty-argument-list/14884347#14884347) I've picked out a few examples of functions without formal arguments to help you understand why they could be useful.

**Functions which have side-effects**

- `plot.new()` for instance, initializes a graphics device.
- Want to update the console buffer?  `flush.console()` has your back.

**Functions which have a narrow purpose**

This is probably the majority of the cases.

- Want to know the date/time?  Call `date()`.
- Want to know the version of R? Call `getRversion()`.