# Identify all functions with an empty argument list

Tags: r

How do I find all functions (available in the current working environment, so `base` plus loaded packages) with a given formal argument signature?

This came up because I was trying to find an example to use to answer this question: [If function(x) can work, why would we need function()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883925/if-functionx-can-work-why-would-we-need-function)

Answer (score 1):

Pieces needed:

- Character vector of all functions: `apropos("^",mode="function")`
- Does a function have no arguments? `length(formals(x))==0`
- Grab the objects named by a character vector `lapply( x, get )`

Thanks to @RichieCotton for [apropos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6982537/636656), and @hadley for `is.primitive`.

```
allFxnNames <- apropos("^",mode="function")
emptyFormals <- function(x) length(formals(x))==0 && !is.primitive(x)
allFxns <- lapply( allFxnNames, get )
whichEmpty <- sapply(allFxns, emptyFormals)
allFxnNames[whichEmpty]
```

This finds all non-primitive functions with no formal arguments:

> "alarm", "closeAllConnections", "colors", "colours", "contributors", 
>   "Cstack_info", "date", "defaultPrototype", "default.stringsAsFactors",
>   "dev.cur", "dev.list", "dev_packages", "element_blank", "empty.dump", 
>   ".First", ".First.sys", "flush.console", "frame", "getAllConnections",
>   "getCConverterDescriptions", "getCConverterStatus", "geterrmessage", 
>   "get_ll_TOL", "get_ll_warn", "getLoadedDLLs", "getNumCConverters", 
>   "get_path", "get_Polypath", "get_PolypathRule", "get_ReplCRS_warn", 
>   "getRversion", "getTaskCallbackNames", "getwd", "graphics.off", 
>   "has_devel", "iconvlist", "is_false", "is.R", "is_true", "Java", 
>   "l10n_info", "last_plot", "licence", "license", "loadedNamespaces", 
>   "loaded_packages", "loadingNamespaceInfo", "memory.profile", 
>   "newEmptyObject", ".NotYetImplemented", ".OptRequireMethods", 
>   "plot.new", "progress_none", "rc.status", "Rdoc", "recordPlot", 
>   "recover", ".rs.activateGraphicsDevice", ".rs.createUUID",
>   ".rs.defaultLibPathIsWriteable",  ".rs.defaultUserLibraryPath",
>   ".rs.disableQuartz", ".rs.helprIsActive",  ".rs.iconvcommon",
>   ".rs.initGraphicsDevice", ".rs.knitrChunkOptions", 
>   ".rs.listJsonRpcHandlers", ".rs.packages.initialize",
>   ".rs.rpc.check_for_package_updates",  ".rs.rpc.get_cran_mirrors",
>   ".rs.rpc.get_package_install_context",  ".rs.rpc.iconvlist",
>   ".rs.rpc.init_default_user_library", ".rs.rpc.list_objects", 
>   ".rs.rpc.list_packages", ".rs.rpc.remove_all_objects",
>   ".rs.setHelprLoadHook",  ".rs.sweaveChunkOptions", "RStudioGD",
>   "RStudio.version", ".rs.uniqueLibraryPaths", 
>   ".rs.updatePackageEvents", ".rs.writeableLibraryPaths", "Rtangle", 
>   "R.Version", "RweaveLatex", "search", "searchpaths", "sessionData", 
>   ".standard_regexps", "stderr", "stdin", "stdout", "sys.calls", 
>   "Sys.Date", "sys.frames", "Sys.getpid", "Sys.info", "Sys.localeconv", 
>   "sys.nframe", "sys.on.exit", "sys.parents", "sys.status", "System", 
>   "Sys.time", "Sys.timezone", "tempdir", "test", "theme_get", "waiver"

Comment: See `?is.primitive` and search for "primitive" on https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/functions

Comment: Also, you could replace the last two lines with `Filter(emptyFormals, allFxns)`

Comment: Finally, you might also want to look at https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/R/find-funs.r - it's not solving the same problem, but it's similar.

Comment: @hadley Most helpful, as usual.  `Filter` doesn't do exactly what I want here, though, as it returns the objects not their names.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your code.  I have ` where <- function(x, f) vapply(x, f, logical(1))` so you could do `allFxnNames[where(allFxns, emptyFormals)]`